# My sql- Count data change over instance in a specific duration

Tags: mysql, sql

Find the below model data given in link where i need to identify how many times the status (column - C data) changed from 2 to 3 with in a specific duration. And i need to group the result based on Id (column A).

please help to sort this out.

[image]

Comment: This is just an image. Where is the mysql query that shows your attempt?

Comment: Edit your question and show your desired results, preferably as a *text* table in the question.

Comment: I dont have an idea to proceed writing query. Data in image is the table data in my database and i need to know for each id how many times status changed from 2 to 3.